# Is it possible to use UTF-8 characters for shapefile attributes?

Tags: shapefile, fields-attributes, encoding

I heard that according to a specification shapefile attributes stored in dbf-files cannot have UTF-8 as encoding.
And then I found out that an additional file with the ending CPG can be used to define the code page to identify the character set used in the dbf file.

For me this sounds contradictory.

So my question is now - is it possible to use UTF-8 characters for shapefile attributes?

and - additional question, since encoding and character sets are always an unpopular topic, do You know a page where the topic is described in detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use UTF-8 characters in shapefile attributes. The document (http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/21106) explains it in detail.